# How do I Parse a non-delimited flat-file

Tags: windows, parsing, text, flat-file

I have some flat files where each line is about 300 characters.  The data has no delimiters of any kind and I want to parse the file to introduce some sort of delimiter between fields.  There are actually about 50 different fields, of varying lengths contained in each line.  All the lines line up nicely.  I am trying to figure a way that I can mark fields in one row and have that extend to all the rows.  There are about 2.5-3 million rows per file.  I am not a programmer so I really need something that already works.  I have been playing with splitting the files into parts and using Excel, but that is taxing the computer system I have, Windows, 8Gb Ram.

I have found a VBA program that loads the files into multiple sheets of Excel. I then have used Excel to parse the data, but it severely taxes the system. Below is an example of a few records. The data fields vary from 1 to 10 characters in length. Since the file is 3 million records I hope to somehow introduce a delimiter in the top row and have that introduced into all the rest of the records. –

Here is the data, the records are longer but you get the idea. The spaces do not necessarily designate a field break

```
11MD122MD4MD MD122999999 MD 4 TX WI 3101 M1088 412110 1D8
11AK122AK4AK AK122999999 AK 4 TX VT 5101 M1066 432311 1W7
```

Some fields might be 5 characters, but only contain 4 visible characters, the last character would be a space. This then allows all records to be the same total length. In the example data I showed, the first 12 characters represent 7 fields. I need to parse this. The remaining record is more of the same. The Excel VBA file only pulls in the records. Each record is contained in a single Excel cell and then needs to be parsed.

Drummo2a
4 mins ago   Edit

Thanks

Comment: can you provide an illustrative example of some of the lines?  If it's possible to do what you're trying to do, you're going to have to come up with some way to find the appropriate place for delimiters.  Maybe we can help you spot one if we see an example

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? "Mark fields" sounds pretty vague - should this involve editing the file?

Comment: I have found a VBA program that loads the files into multiple sheets of Excel.  I then have used Excel to parse the data, but it severely taxes the system.  Below is an example of a few records.  The data fields vary from 1 to 10 characters in length.  Since the file is 3 million records I hope to somehow introduce a delimiter in the top row and have that introduced into all the rest of the records.

Comment: Here is the data, the records are longer but you get the idea.  The spaces do not necessarily designate a field break      11MD122MD4MD  MD122999999 MD    4   TX  WI  3101  M1088 412110  1D8

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it

Comment: "There are ... about 50 different fields, of varying lengths contained in each line. All the lines line up nicely."  If the lengths of each line vary, what does it mean for them to "line up nicely"?  I'm trying to spot some algorithm for distinguishing the fields, but I don't see one yet

Comment: Each row is much longer than shown, but won't fit in the editor here.  The spaces don't necessarily mean field breaks.  That is the problem, there is no way to find the field breaks, they will have to be defined.  I just want to define them once and then apply them to all 3 million rows.

Comment: All the lines are the same length, some of the fields have spaces if no character is present

Comment: "there is no way to find the field breaks" - what does that mean? That a space at one position might define a delimiter between two fields, but not at a different position? How does that VBA script you already use handle this situation? What keeps you from adapting this code into anything else?

Comment: How can the lines be the same length if the fields aren't the same length?  What's the logic behind that assertion?

Comment: Some fields might be 5 characters, but only contain 4 visible characters, the last character would be a space.  This then allows all records to be the same total length.  In the example data I showed, the first 12 characters represent 7 fields.  I need to parse this.  The remaining record is more of the same.  The Excel VBA file only pulls in the records.  Each record is contained in a single Excel cell and then needs to be parsed.

Comment: " allows all records to be the same total length.  In the example data I showed, the first 12 characters represent 7 fields."  So, in every line, each field is the same length?  So really all you have to do is read each line, and take the first `a` characters for field 1, the next `b` characters for field 2, etc? "the last character would be a space" and it sounds like you might also want to trim off those spaces.

Comment: Yes, that would work.  I am not a programmer.  Is there a program that will do that for me?

Comment: I added the `windows` tag because it sounds like you're looking for a way to do this in that native environment.  You can use GNU cut to do this, but I don't think you'll have that in windows.  If you have / don't mind installing a python interpreter, doing the same in python would be pretty straight forward and we could offer some code to get you started.  I realize that pushes you out of your comfort zone.

Comment: That may be what I have to do.  Unfortunately I need permission to install anything on my work computer.  You have helped me further define my dilemma though! I was hoping there might be some free online, or cheap editor that will do what I want, but I have not been able to find one that doesn't require that I write the code.